# Magento 2 - di.xml virtual type - overriding a class

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

i have a module which overrides the ShippingMethodConverter class. I made the configuration in my di.xml like so:

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter"
            type="MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter"/>                                

<virtualType name="mynamespace_mymodule_quote_mode_cart_shippingmethodconverter" type="\MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="shippingMethodConverter" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to 
Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement::__construct() 
must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter, 
instance of MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter given, 
called in /path_to_magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php 
on line 93 and defined in 
/path_to_magento/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php on line 62
```

My class starts like this:

```
namespace MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Model\Cart;

/**
 * Quote shipping method data.
 *
 */
class ShippingMethodConverter
{
..
```

As I understand the virtualType correctly I want to say that my class should be handled like the given argument in order to guarantee that there are no type parsing errors in the magento core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is based on this

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter"
            type="MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter"/>
```

With this configuration you're telling Magento's automatic constructor dependency injection system that whenever it sees a `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter` in a constructor, it should instantiate a `MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter` object instead of a `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter` object.

Magento's doing this correctly, but because your object failed the type hint check in the constructor, PHP bailed with an error.  Your class needs to extend the `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter` class (or implement it if `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter` is an interface)

Comment: thank for your answer. Know it works fine for ShippingMethodConverter. I just have one more question about an interface which I want to override. Cause I got the following error: Cannot instantiate interface MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface. As I undestand it correctly I can only assign a class and not an interface for the virtual type. Or how does it work with interfaces? Thank you in advance

Comment: @StephanHofmann I'm afraid that's a little too vague for me to answer with 100% certainty, but it sounds like your configuration is trying to instantiate an interface.  You would need to create a `<preference>` for your interface that told Magento which concrete class it should instantiate when it encounters a `MyNameSpace\MyModule\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface`